# ASP.NET MVC 3 Restrict access to a view based on time of year/accessible date range

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3, with Razor views. I have two action methods (Get and Post) in a controller that have a single corresponding view (.cshtml file). In my app, I want to allow access to that view only during certain times of the year, let's call it the "accessible date range." During all times not within the accessible date range, I'd like the app to provide the user an error message instead of displaying the page. What is a good way to go about this? Could a custom attribute be used on the controller methods? Should the logic go directly in the two controller methods? Should I just use an `if` statement in the view file along with the appropriate logic? I'm not crazy about putting this logic in a view file, and would like suggestions for a cleaner option.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses everyone. Sounds like you all (John H, Mark Oreta and KingCronus) are in agreement. Went with first response for accepted answer, but I appreciate the additional comments from the others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest answer would be put the logic inside your controller:

```
public ActionResult SummerOnly()
{
   if (!(DateTime.Now > new DateTime(2012,8,8)))
       return View("Error");    

   return View("GoodView");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could make a custom attribute, but my preference would be to put the logic into the Controller myself. I only tend to use a custom attribute if I know it is something I will be reusing over and over within the application.

Then it is a simple case of checking if the date is within certain dates, and then firing off to different views dependant on the result.

It should never be in the View, as I think you already know from your question.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to do this would be to put the logic in the action method.  Certainly don't do it in the view as that's not the view's responsibility.  You could make an attribute for this, and I would definitely go this route if you plan on reusing it, otherwise I'd keep it simple and just place the logic in the action method.

Answer (score 0):

For a one off use case, then an attribute is overkill, but if you did need to reuse the logic then an attribute would be ideal. Something like this:

```
public class RestrictDate : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private int _monthFrom ;
    private int _monthTo;

    private int _dayFrom = 1;
    private int _dayTo = 0;

    public RestrictDate(int monthFrom, int monthTo)
    {            
        _monthFrom = monthFrom;
        _monthTo = monthTo;

    }

    public RestrictDate(int monthFrom, int dayFrom, int monthTo, int dayTo)
        : this(monthFrom, monthTo)
    {
        _dayFrom = dayFrom;
        _dayTo = dayTo;
    }

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {

        DateTime minDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, _monthFrom, _dayFrom);

        int interval = _monthFrom <= _monthTo ? _monthTo - _monthFrom : 12 - _monthFrom  + _monthTo;

        DateTime maxDate;
        if (_dayTo == 0)
        {
            maxDate = minDate.AddMonths(interval + 1).AddDays(-1);
        }
        else
        {
            maxDate = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year, _monthFrom, 1).AddMonths(interval).AddDays(_dayTo - 1);
        }

        if (DateTime.Today < minDate || DateTime.Today > maxDate)
        {
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(new RouteValueDictionary(new
            {
                controller = "Home",
                action = "Error"
            }));
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Clearly this isn't production ready code - there is no validation of the inputs etc, but I think you get the idea.